# Keyword Labeling in Google Looker Studio

Tags: metrics, keyword, looker-studio, google-search-console, dimension

I want to label Google Search Console keywords in Google Looker Studio. I tried doing to do so using a `CASE` as well as an `IF` function:

```
CASE 
WHEN Average Position <= 10 THEN "High Ranking" 
WHEN Average Position <= 20 THEN "Mid Ranking" 
WHEN Average Position > 20 THEN "Low Ranking" 
END
```

and

```
IF(Average Position <= 10, "High Ranking", 
IF(Average Position <= 20, "Mid Ranking", 
"Low Ranking"))
```

Both result in a metric containing the values "High Ranking", "Mid Ranking" and "Low Ranking". However, I want this to be a dimension. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an error in your logic and have corrected it below, This code works for me to create a dimension from a calculated field. Let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

```
   CASE 
   WHEN Average Position <= 10 THEN "High Ranking"
   WHEN Average Position > 10 AND Average Position < 21 THEN "Mid Ranking"
   WHEN Average Position >= 21 THEN "Low Ranking"
   END
```

Comment: Hi @Max_Stone Thanks for answering!

When I use your code I get a new metric field (blue with ABC as type). I want to know what keywords are high, mid or low ranked and how many impressions and clicks each ranking category has.

Having the blue metric with ABC type field, I cannot use the field as a dimension in a table. Instead, I want to be it a green dimension field with ABC type.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Hi @KimvanDijk, I would use filters for that. you can use AVE position to filter just not to group on, you can also use it in conditional formatting